# python winapi check if sheet exists

Tags: python, excel, winapi

i am using this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel_file = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_file.Workbooks.Open(excel_result_path)
excel_file.Visible = 1
mySheet = excel_file.Worksheets.Add()
mySheet.Name = "name"
```

which works fine.
the only problem is, if the sheet allready exists, i get an error telling me, that the sheet already exists

> File "..\dynamic.py", line 554, in **setattr**
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, 'Microsof
>   t Excel', 'Kann einem Blatt nicht den gleichen Namen geben wie einem anderen Bla
>   tt, einer Objektbibliothek oder einer Arbeitsmappe, auf die Visual Basic Bezug n
>   immt.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

so my question is, how can i check if an excel-sheet-name allready exists ?

Comment: Could you catch the exception? Or see if "name" is in wb.Sheets.Name? What do you want to do if it exists already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'name' in [excel_file.Sheets(i).Name for i in range(1,excel_file.Sheets.Count+1)]
```

Comment: A different solution is at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37966737/1305322

Comment: yes but that solution uses a library not part of the OP's original question

Comment: The library op uses can't do what op asks

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more readable solution:

```py
'name' in [sheet.Name for sheet in excel_file.Sheets]
```